# Python3: change dictionary key from string to tuple of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say I got a dict:

> {'I like': 14, 'you like': 12, 'he likes': 2}

I would like to change into to be like:

> {('I', 'like'):14, ('you', 'like'):12. ('he','likes'):2}

So I want to change keys of the dict form strings to tuple of strings.
I tried to make it:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
...    
d = {make_tuple(k): d[k] for k in d}
```

but I got:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    of the
         ^
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Its's a list `['I like': 14, 'you like', 12, 'he likes', 2]` not dict.

Comment: @AmitTripathi Yes this is how I display my dict. Now I have edited the question to show its adict.

Comment: @M.T I read that items make additional copy of dict and I want it to be effective.

Comment: no, `.items()` generates a view, not a copy.

Comment: If d is your dictionary this is your answer: `{"{}".format(tuple(k.split())): v for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: `new_dict = {tuple(k.split()): d[k] for k in d}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need the builtin `tuple()`:

```
source = {'I like': 14, 'you like': 12, 'he likes': 2}

target = { tuple(k.split()):source[k] for k in source}

print(target)
```

Output:

```
{('I', 'like'): 14, ('you', 'like'): 12, ('he', 'likes'): 2}
```

p.s.

Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'I like': 14, 'you like': 12, 'he likes': 2}
new_d = {tuple(k.split()): v for k, v in d.items()}

new_d
```

#### output:

```
{('I', 'like'): 14, ('he', 'likes'): 2, ('you', 'like'): 12}
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong as he wants a tuple with two elements: `('I', 'like').

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> original = {'I like': 14, 'you like': 12, 'he likes': 2}
>>> new_d = {tuple(k.split()): v for k,v in original.items()}
>>> new_d
{('I', 'like'): 14, ('you', 'like'): 12, ('he', 'likes'): 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with two ways:

> Data:

```
your_data={'I like': 14, 'you like': 12, 'he likes': 2}
```

> One line solution:

```
print({tuple(key.split()):value for key,value in your_data.items()})
```

> output:

```
{('I', 'like'): 14, ('he', 'likes'): 2, ('you', 'like'): 12}
```

> Detailed solution:

Above dict comprehension is same as :

```
final_dict={}
for key,value in your_data.items():
    final_dict[tuple(key.split())]=value

print(final_dict)
```

> output:

```
{('I', 'like'): 14, ('he', 'likes'): 2, ('you', 'like'): 12}
```